# How to export a large data set to excel in client-side?

Tags: excel, performance, export-to-excel, client-side, large-data

If the JSON data size is around 40 to MB in size (around 60K rows with 20 columns approximately). What's the best client-side library to be used for exporting to excel?

Comment: I tried using datatables.net buttons export and this is crashing in IE and Edge browsers.

Comment: Also, i tried to implement SheetJS /js-xlsx library - this is running out of memory. I dont have any issue with chrome browser. This is really an issue on IE 11 and Edge browsers. Any pointers on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for as js is concerned there is limit to it set by JavaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength, otherwise json can sent as much data as possible. IE crashes because it can not handle so much data so you should send 8k blocks of data and then properly join them to get full document on client side

Comment: Do you've any pointers/examples on joining the data on client side?

Comment: As per this (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/61), even JSZip library also don't have this kind of support.